# Create new Google Spreadsheets with timestamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I'm trying to create a new spreadsheet once we select the specific function from the custom menu item that's selected.  I want the new spreadsheet to be "Sheet" and "Timestamp".

I have this created but it's giving an error:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Generate Traffic Sheet", functionName: "newSheet"}];

  ss.addMenu("Generate Traffic Sheet", menuEntries);
}

function newSheet () {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(name)
    var d = new Date();
    var timeStamp = d.getTime();
    ss.setName(timeStamp)
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: Hi Jacob, Thanks for the help. I screwed up with fully detailing out my task. I actually don't want a brand new spreadsheet created, rather an additional worksheet (tab) within' the current spreadsheet, with that current spreadsheet labeled as "Traffic Sheet" & Date(). How would that end up looking? Is it just a separate functional rather than SpreadsheetApp.create?

Comment: That would be a different question altogether. Why don't you accept this answer, because it fits the question, and ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to accomplish your task:

### Code

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Sheet 1", functionName: "newSheet1"},
                     {name: "Sheet 2", functionName: "newSheet2"}]
  ss.addMenu("Generate Traffic Sheet", menuEntries);
}

function newSheet1 () {
  var name = "test"; 
  SpreadsheetApp.create(name).getRange("A1").setValue(new Date());
}

function newSheet2 () {
  var name = "test"; 
  var myDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy");
  SpreadsheetApp.create(name).getRange("A1").setValue(myDate);
}
```

### Remarks

- If you would've ran the debugger, then you would've noticed an error
  message: "name variable doesn't exist". See sheet 1 example.
- setName() method isn't applicable here for adding data into the other sheet.
- If you want to access the new spreadsheet, then you need to create that instance as well.
- the getTime() method will return the amount of millisecond from 01-01-1970 on.
- I've added two revised code samples, so that you can see the difference

Good luck and happy coding !!