# Create new sheet with a "template" based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to do run some stats on the AFL (Australian Football league) here in Australia and want to get some better understanding on players form based on some key stats.=
In order to do this, I would like to check if a URL exists and returns response code 200 and if so then create a new spreadsheet with the query ID of the URL.
A URL looks like this https://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/fts_match_statistics?mid=9721

My editable spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v3DNQwkdaD7YX63JWUzUKxPve6oTEYZOfXGhE_Uz_Xg/edit?usp=sharing).

What I have done so far is create a script to check if a URL (Column A) exists, the response of that is stored in Column B.

The code I use to check the URL is

```
​function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
    var response_code ;
    try {
        response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
    }
    catch( error ) {
        response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;
    }
    finally {
        return response_code;
    }
}
```

What I​'m trying to do is:

1. Check a list of URLs if they exist or not (See Tab "Active" Column
   A)
2. If the URL exists then the script will return a value in Column B = "200"
3. Then create a new spreadsheet with the bold highlighted part of the URL (e.g. 9721 in the above URL)
4. The new spreadsheet should then have the formula below in cell A1

   `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/fts_match_statistics?mid=9721&sby=14#t1","table",12)`.

   The URL in the formula is the same URL that was checked in Step 1.

I thought I can check if the repsonse_code is 200 then add a new sheet, but somehow that ends up in an error all the time.
If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Hey Ruben, this formula works fine. What I'm trying to do is create a new sheet if the response code is 200 for a certain URL and then in the new sheet use that formula.

Comment: Ok so first of all use Google Script to check if a URL exists and does not return 404. That is in my spreadsheet in the Google Script. 
Then if the response from that script is "200", then create a new Tab and in that new tab run the formula you have mentioned in your first comment.

Comment: How can I automatically create a new sheet and then in that sheet run the formula mentioned using the URL that had the response code 200.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include that and include a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Related: [Create new Google Spreadsheets with timestamp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/47157/88163)

Comment: Updated it a bit. Will improve further later on.

Comment: It looks that you are looking that someone write the script for you. There use to be several community members that answered this kind of questions but it looks that they aren't participating nowadays. What I would like to see in questions about [tag:google-apps-script] is brief description of the OP's search/research efforts as well of their attempts to write the script by themself but maybe you should start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and perhaps making more specific questions, like how to read spreadsheet values.